# MySQL Group By and HAVING

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I'm a MySQL query noobie so I'm sure this is a question with an obvious answer.

But, I was looking at these two queries.  Will they return different result sets? I understand that the sorting process would commence differently, but I believe they will return the same results with the first query being slightly more efficient?

Query 1: HAVING, then AND

```
SELECT user_id   
FROM forum_posts  
GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING COUNT(id) >= 100   
    AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM banned_users)
```

Query 2: WHERE, then HAVING

```
SELECT user_id   
FROM forum_posts 
WHERE user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM banned_users) 
GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING COUNT(id) >= 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the first query will be less efficient (`HAVING` applied after `WHERE`).
**UPDATE**

Some pseudo code to illustrate how your queries are executed ([very] simplified version).
 First query:
1. `SELECT user_id FROM forum_posts`
2. `SELECT user_id FROM banned_user`
3. Group, count, etc.
4. Exclude records from the first result set if they are presented in the second

Second query
1. `SELECT user_id FROM forum_posts`
2. `SELECT user_id FROM banned_user`
3. Exclude records from the first result set if they are presented in the second
4. Group, count, etc.

The order of steps 1,2 is not important, mysql can choose whatever it thinks is better. The important difference is in steps 3,4. Having is applied after `GROUP BY`. Grouping is usually more expensive than joining (excluding records can be considering as join operation in this case), so the fewer records it has to group, the better performance.

Comment: great, thanks! Interesting, I'll have to run some tests.  I thought more efficient because there's less records to compare the NOT IN banned_users portion after it's grouped than before? If that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that condition would be tested only for the grouped by results, not all, before the grouping.

Comment: @kimmothy: The subquery in `NOT IN` really needs to be executed only once.

Comment: I've added an update to illustrate a difference between the queries.

Comment: @a1ex07: are you sure there is difference in the actual execution plans?

Comment: It should be a difference. At least in `EXTRA`.

Comment: Did you run the query using EXPLAIN to make sure this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

You have already answers that **the two queries will show same results** and various opinions for which one is more efficient.

My opininion is that there will be a **difference in efficiency** (speed), **only if** the optimizer yields with **different plans** for the 2 queries. I think that for the latest MySQL versions the optimizers are smart enough to find the same plan for either query so there will be **no difference at all** but off course one can test and see either the excution plans with EXPLAIN or running the 2 queries against some test tables.

I would use the second version in any case, just to play safe.

---

Let me add that:

- `COUNT(*)` is usually more efficient than `COUNT(notNullableField)` in MySQL. Until that is fixed in future MySQL versions, use `COUNT(*)` where applicable.

Therefore, you can also use:

```
SELECT user_id   
FROM forum_posts 
WHERE user_id NOT IN
  ( SELECT user_id FROM banned_users ) 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100
```

- There are also other ways to achieve same (to `NOT IN`) sub-results before applying `GROUP BY`.

Using `LEFT JOIN / NULL` :

```
SELECT fp.user_id   
FROM forum_posts AS fp
  LEFT JOIN banned_users AS bu
    ON bu.user_id = fp.user_id
WHERE bu.user_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY fp.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100
```

Using `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT fp.user_id   
FROM forum_posts AS fp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM banned_users AS bu
    WHERE bu.user_id = fp.user_id
  ) 
GROUP BY fp.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100
```

Which of the 3 methods is faster depends on your table sizes and a lot of other factors, so best is to test with your data.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING conditions are applied to the *grouped by* results, and since you group by user_id, all of their possible values will be present in the grouped result, so the placing of the user_id condition is not important.

Comment: Placing is important. If the `WHERE` is applied, the grouping is done in fewer rows (even zero), so the COUNT() has to be computed for only those rows. If it is left for the `HAVING` clause, the grouping (and counting) is done on all rows and then the condition is checked. Result: if banned users are a great percentage of all users, the difference is speed will be great (proportionally)

Comment: Off course the difference in speed exists only if the optimizer yields with different plans for the 2 queries.

Comment: Thanks for pointig it out, I really learned a lot from the answers here. :)

Answer (score 0):

To me, second query is more efficient because it lowers the number of records for GROUP BY and HAVING.

Alternatively, you may try the following query to avoid using IN:

```
SELECT `fp`.`user_id`
FROM `forum_posts` `fp`
LEFT JOIN `banned_users` `bu` ON `fp`.`user_id` = `bu`.`user_id`
WHERE `bu`.`user_id` IS NULL
GROUP BY `fp`.`user_id`
HAVING COUNT(`fp`.`id`) >= 100
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

No it does not gives same results.

Because first query will filter records from count(id) condition

Another query filter records and then apply having clause.

**Second Query is correctly written**

Comment: Since you are saying the results will be different, you can hardly claim which one is correctly written before you know what problem is being solved. At the very least, they are both correct *syntactically*. And, in fact, the results will be the same too. It's the efficiency that they will differ in.

Comment: @Andriy: are you sure there is difference in efficiency?

Comment: @ypercube: I'd expect HAVING to evaluate after WHERE, and, in fact, even after GROUP BY (which, I think, is calculated after WHERE too). Thus the first query would unnecessarily calculate counts for rows that would later be discarded based on `user_id`. The second one filters out on `user_id` before aggregating.